# IntelliJ can't run gradle project due to missing Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I just gave *IntelliJ* a try, because *Eclipse* annoyed me again. I imported my *gradle* project(jetty, vaadin) and it went quite smoothly. But when I tried to run it I encountered the following error message during "make":

> Error:gradle-resources-test:vaadinsharedwidgets: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/util/ReaderInputStream

"vaadinsharedwidgets" is a module of the project. From what I understand from the error, IntelliJ doesn't find ant, but this is intended because I don't use ant. It also not part of the transitive dependencies. The same project runs in eclipse fine and also building it in gradle works without any problems.

**Update:** I just checked in Eclipse and somehow the ant.jar is on the classpath in Eclipse but I can't link it to any project. I wonder how it got there.

**Update2:** Missing version information:

- IntelliJ: v14.0.1 CE (no plugins)
- Gradle: 2.2 (used via wrapper)
- Java 8 (1.8.0 b05)
- Vaadin 7.3.4

---

`build.gradle`:

```
apply from: 'http://nexus/gradle/vaadin.gradle'
apply from: 'http://nexus/gradle/java8.gradle'

version = '1.1'

description = "Gemeinsame Vaadin-Widgets"

vaadin.widgetset  'net.xyz.vaadinsharedwidgets.VaadinsharedWidgetsWidgetset'

dependencies {
    compile project(':ibhtheme')
    compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-server:' + vaadin.version
    compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-client:' + vaadin.version
}

jar{
    // Include source in jar
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir  'src/main/webapp'
```

---

`vaadin.gradle:`

```
apply from: 'http://plugins.jasoft.fi/vaadin.plugin?version=0.9.2'

configurations {
    def conf = 'vaadin-client'
    def sources = project.sourceSets.main
    def testSources = project.sourceSets.test

    if (!project.configurations.hasProperty(conf)) {
        project.configurations.create(conf)

        sources.compileClasspath += project.configurations[conf]
        testSources.compileClasspath += project.configurations[conf]
        testSources.runtimeClasspath += project.configurations[conf]

        project.configurations[conf].exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty' 
    }
}


vaadin {
    version '7.3.4'
    push true
}
```

---

`java8.gradle:`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

group = 'net.xyz'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.3.RELEASE'

    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.7'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.3.RELEASE'
}
```

Adding ant as an additional dependency to the module doesn't work.

Comment: Gradle actually contains Ant so you can re-use existing Ant tasks. You didn't include your gradle build or the version. In fact you didn't include anything outside of the error, which makes it hard for anyone to help.

Comment: Sorry about the missing information. I added the relevant versions.

Comment: Please include the build.gradle from the vaadinsharedwidgets module.

Comment: Does the gradle build work from the command line? This will identify if the problem is related to Gradle or Intellij. Does Intellij Community Edition contain everything needed to build a Vaadin project? It is missing key web stuff, as far as I'm aware. You can try the Ultimate edition free for 30 days.

Comment: I added the build.gradle file plus its dependencies.
Building from the command line works fine.
The Project uses an embedded jetty, so i guessed I'm fine without any application server support by IntelliJ.

Comment: I checked the Vaadin website and it should work with the Community Edition. Thanks for your patients.

Comment: Have you managed to fix the missing classDef issue? I stuck with one myself right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tinkering and try-and-error I found that the following code in the vaadin.gradle was the culprit and removed it:

```
configurations {
    def conf = 'vaadin-client'
    def sources = project.sourceSets.main
    def testSources = project.sourceSets.test

    if (!project.configurations.hasProperty(conf)) {
        project.configurations.create(conf)

        sources.compileClasspath += project.configurations[conf]
        testSources.compileClasspath += project.configurations[conf]
        testSources.runtimeClasspath += project.configurations[conf]

        project.configurations[conf].exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty' 
    }
}
```

It was part of an outdated hack to use jetty9 instead of jetty8, which was used by older versions of the vaadin-gradle plugin. The current version uses 9.2.2 which seems to be fine.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same error in a Java project with multiple subprojects in IntelliJ 14.

Updating to 15.0.1, refreshing the Gradle projects via `Views → Tool Windows → Gradle` in IntelliJ and restarting fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you mean 15.0.1?  Anyway, I still have the problem.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147146 ; File / Invalidate Caches+Restart seems to help.

Comment: Invalidation of Cache & Restart works - this should probably be an answer @MartinVysny

Answer (score 3):

Choose `File → Invalidate Caches / Restart` from the menu and select `Invalidate and Restart`.  That fixed the issue for me.